# How to print out individual numbers after ordering an array in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and having some issues printing out individual numbers after sorting an array.
I have the following....

```
 for x  in ${array[@]}
               do
                  echo $x
               done| sort
```

This is the only way I was able to print out the entire array in **order**. 
Now I'm trying to print out a single item after **it's been ordered**
so I tried....

```
for x  in ${array[@]}
                   do
                      echo ${array[2]}
                      exit
                   done| sort
```

But it prints the third item in the **unordered array** array instead. 
Any help?

Comment: You should store the sorted array somewhere and then print its third item

Comment: I tried that, but things got  really messy. I will try to do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the variable and then trying to sort the ONLY variable that you have printed (in your case `${array[2]}`)

Try this:

```
sorted=($(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"|sort))
echo ${sorted[2]}
```

This sorts the array and stores it in another array `sorted`

Comment: thanks. It just prints a bunch of spaces instead of numbers

Comment: Let me know what you see when you do `echo ${sorted[@]}`

Comment: If you run `echo ${array[@]}` ?

Comment: if I do sorted=($x). Then echo ${sorted[@]}. It prints out the ordered array. but echo ${sorted[2]} are blank spaces

Comment: I dont understand what you are telling. What do you get if you print `echo ${array[@]}` and then do `echo ${sorted[@]}`

Comment: @frazlin. Sorry, it works! I screwed something up along the way but it's all good now. Thanks so much!